# Select a Cell In the Last Row of ListObject

Tags: excel, vba

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to pass a row count value stored in a variable to a Cell argument.

Basically, I am trying to find the last row of a ListObject, and paste a value into the 26th cell of that row. I have tried reading through all of Microsoft Docs, and I just figure it out. Please help! I am posting the code from the entire module for contextual reference.

```
'This code will copy the content of the form from the Entry Form worksheet'
'and paste the content on an empty row in the VioLog table on the Violation Records worksheet.'

Sub AddRecord()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim rFormFields As Range
Dim casePart1 As Range
Dim bolFormFieldEmpty As Boolean
Dim lstRow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim loVioLog As ListObject

Set casePart1 = Worksheets("Violation Records").Range("H3")
Set rFormFields = Range("D12:D13, D16:D20, D23:D33, D36, D39:D45")
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Violation Records")
'Set loVioLog = Worksheets("Violation Records").ListObject("VioLog").Range

rFormFieldEmpty = True 'Initalize vairable

For Each Cell In rFormFields
  If Cell.Value = "" Then
  bolFormFieldEmpty = True
  Else
  bolFormFieldEmpty = False
  GoTo Continue
  End If
Next

If bolFormFieldEmpty = True Then
  MsgBox "The form is empty. Complete the form and click 'Submit'", vbExclamation, "BCAD Security: Empty Form Notice"
  GoTo EndProcedure
End If

Continue:

'Copy range of cells from Entry Form'
Sheets("Violation Entry Form").Activate
rFormFields.Select
Selection.Copy

'Add row to violation record log'
Sheets("Violation Records").Activate
Range("B9").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

'Pastes the selected values on an empty row of the Violation Records worksheet.'
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllExceptBorders, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        True, Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Creates case number for new entry.
casePart1.Select
casePart1.Copy
lstRow = sht.ListObjects("VioLog").Range.Rows.Count
'MsgBox ("The number of rows in the Violation Record Log are " & lstRow)
ListObjects ("VioLog")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26).Select
'ActiveSheet.Paste
'Selection.Copy
'ActiveCell.Offset(0, -27).Select


'Activate Entry Form.'
Sheets("Violation Entry Form").Activate
'Range("D40").Select

'Call confirmation message box.'
'MessageBoxTimer
MessageBox
ClearForm

EndProcedure:
 
End Sub

Sub MessageBox()

'This code generates a message box that informs the user the data entered was saved, '
'and also informs the user of the case number from the last row of the VioLog table.'


MsgBox "If editing your entry is required, use the 'Search'" _
& " feature on the 'Violation Records' tab " _
& "to find the record you wish to edit.", _
vbInformation, "BCAD Security Division - Record Saved"

MsgBox "Your Case Number is ", vbExclamation, "BCAD Security - Case No."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ListRows.Count`:

```
Set loVioLog = Worksheets("Violation Records").ListObjects("VioLog") '<~ note the s, ListObjects

With loVioLog
    .ListRows(.ListRows.Count).Range.Cells(26).Value = yourvariablehere
End With
```

**EDIT**:
Note that you can use the following to reference the 26th cell in the last row of the table:

```
.Cells(26)
.Cells(, 26)
.Columns(26)
```

Comment: Sorry for nit picking, maybe it is more appropriate (readable at least) the way it was written before, since you can use `Columns` instead of `Cells`: `Columns(26)` or `Cells(, 26)` both immediately indicating that `26` is a column number. Maybe include `Columns` in your answer.

Comment: So it seems that you can use an object as a value for a property, such as `.ListRows(.ListRows.Count)`. Did I get that right? Is there a reference for this in a book somewhere?

Comment: @RashadJackson - `.ListRows.Count` is not an object. Unless I'm misunderstanding your comment.